# How do I correct system fonts that are suddenly italic?

Tags: windows-10, fonts

My Windows 10 system appears to have a problem with fonts.  In a number of places the font being displayed is italic where it should not be.  For instance, in Google Hangouts:

[No idea why this is italic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh0ya.png)

I also note that the same problem occurs in my Angular Material app that I am building, which leasds me to believe that it has something to do with the Roboto font?

Anyone have any ideas why italics are appearing in strange places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you suspect a problem with the Roboto font, the simplest solution is to delete
it and re-install:

- Open *Control Panel > Fonts*
- Select the Roboto variants you see, note down their names, then right-click
  one and choose *Delete*
- Download the [Roboto font](https://www.dafont.com/roboto.font)
- Unzip the file `roboto.zip`
- Select the Roboto variants that you wish to install and drag them to the
  window of *Control Panel > Fonts*

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

had a similar issue and could find no help online. turns out the regular version of Consolas (which is set to the default sys monospace font when VS is installed, i think) was removed when some thrid-party application was uninstalled. i just had to find the consolas.tff file online and [manually install it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-font-b7c5f17c-4426-4b53-967f-455339c564c1), which fixed everything. i imagine similar things happen with various font families depending on installations, so worth checking the default system fonts for completeness

Answer (score 0):

You can go there : **C:\Windows\Fonts**

At your left click on : Adjust ClearType

Adjust your ClearType how you want.

It will change the italic display.